# Generating and ordering timezone regions

Tags: php, timezone, datetimeoffset

How do I output timezone offsets based on the list of regions present in http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php ?

Ideally, I would like it "arranged" in UTC-12:00 to UTC+12:00 format.

So,

```
America/New_York should generate UTC-4:00
UTC should be UTC
Asia/Damascus should be UTC+3:00
etc
```

It should match http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones in its output of course...

---

Q2: Is there some standardized order in which I can display this list? Of course, GMT-11 to GMT+12, but since many regions overlap, how should I be displaying those? All of these regions will be part of one dropdown:

```
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/Niue
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/Apia
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/Midway
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/Pago_Pago
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Fakaofo
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Rarotonga
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Johnston
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Tahiti
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/Honolulu
   [but what order should the above be in?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply ordered by offset and then alphabetical. Would have preferred a more 'geographic' approach - but didnt find anything pointing out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('time_zone_string')
```

consult the manual to see the available time zones

edit:

readding a second time i see i am not answering your question clearly,  you can use this function:

```
DateTimeZone::getOffset();
```

more details found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php)